# Why did an ISP outage reset my blockchain to only 78MB?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I don't understand what happened, but after a week of waiting for Geth to complete the blockchain download using `geth --rpc` and reaching 31GB's of data downloaded so far. My ISP had an outage due to a storm yesterday morning, I lost service twice in one day. Now that my ISP is up again, I checked the Geth download and it hasn't moved since the first outage happened about 20 hours ago.

More then that I suddenly have an extra 30GB's of free space on my hard drive and Geth folder only has 78MB's of data in it. It's practically empty. I'm confused, why did the part of the blockchain I download suddenly disappear and start back at essentially 0 and Geth is currently just sitting there not doing anything.

I would really be grateful for advice on what's happening and how I can prevent it from happening again. Also, I'm doing this to mine ethereum, so I assume I need to download the full and complete blockchain. What is it currently at, about 60GB's? Which is fine.

Anyway, again I'm grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, haven't seen that geth "deletes" data during an outage. But if your system was affected, maybe the data was in some cache, and not yet written to disk? The provider may not use a local disk, they have usually arrays, that are shared between machines. Also, it is possible, that they have re-imaged your system to the last "best known" state. Just thinking out loud, not finger pointing... 
When I downloaded last recently (slightly below 4mio blocks in July 2017), I had ~25 Gig on my harddisk, using "geth --fast --cache=2048". When you don't use "--fast" for the very first time, it can get a lot bigger. My observation is +100Gig, but you may want to search yourself with the two words blockchain and size. At best the results are confusing, from "you cannot determine current blockchain size" (!) up to specific values like I just provided ...

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Turns out I had panicked to quickly. I was able to find where the data was at and the download started up again on its own.